# Lumen Routes shows 404 except root route

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, lumen

I am using Lumen for the first time. I placed my lumen files in folder Test and kept the folder inside /var/www/html path in server. My PHP version is **7.4.3**

I have the following routes:

```
$router->get('/key', function() {
return str_random(32);
});

$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
return $router->app->version();
});
```

Below is my htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But whenever I try to access http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Test/public/key it shows

> The requested URL was not found on this server.

But if I try to access http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Test/public/ it returns me

Lumen (5.7.8) (Laravel Components 5.7.*)

How can I make all other routes also to work?

Comment: You should set up a vhost with the `public` folder as DocumentRoot or use `php -S localhost:8000 -t public` from your project folder. https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/6.x#installing-lumen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I searched for **< Directory /var/www/ >** in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file and changed the below

```
AllowOverride None
```

to

```
AllowOverride All
```

and ***restarted the apache***. It solved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

It seems rewrite rule is disabled

`sudo a2enmod rewrite`

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: than you have to configure your hosts or try to change APP_URL=http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Test/public in .env file, but I think you need to configure hosts however